# Freestyle flickering problem

Tags: rendering, freestyle

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ouWvcSiaeyg&ab_channel=Stesiek1235

I’ve made a freestyle Black/White outline and for an unknown reason, some of the outlines flickers. I have many scenes but only in this one, I’m having this problem.
Does anyone know any fix?
I tried searching on google but nothing seemed to work
I tried soo many things in freestyle options for several hours now.

Comment: Hello ! Hard to say but try to make sure you don't have any duplicate hidden object where the flickering happens

Comment: Inside of the mesh you mean?

Comment: Sometimes when modelling you duplicate your objects and hide them, but it does not hide them from rendering. So the renderer sees duplicate geometry on the exact same place and has to randomly decide which polygons to render. The concept is a bit complicated and it may not be the culprit in your case, if you're interested in looking it up, it's called *Z-fighting*

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. I unhide everything, moved a few models, tried to work with a single cube instead of a building, deleted all the lights near the building, deleted this wireframed fence between the buildings, tried to duplicate a scene, messed around with freestyle options, but the same thing happens.